# Error when I tried covert json with null to model use GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have String witj Json:

```
String str = "[{
    "serviceid": "312",
    "servicetype": "0",
    "nextrecurringchargedate": "null"
},
{
    "serviceid": "104",
    "servicetype": "0",
    "nextrecurringchargedate": "null"
},
{
    "serviceid": "310",
    "servicetype": "0",
    "nextrecurringchargedate": "null"
}]";
```

And I have model:

```
public class NextChDay {
    @SerializedName("serviceid")
    private Long serviceId;
    @SerializedName("servicetype")
    private Long serviceType;
    @SerializedName("nextrecurringchargedate")
    private Date nextrecurringchargedate;

    public NextChDay() {
    }

    public NextChDay(Long serviceId, Long serviceType, Date nextrecurringchargedate) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
        this.nextrecurringchargedate = nextrecurringchargedate;
    }
```

//getters and setters

And I want conver Json to model use GSON library

```
NextChDay[] nextChDays = GSON.fromJson(str, NextChDay[].class);
```

But I have an error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null"
```

Previously, I had no problems with "null" and I don't understand how resolve this trouble. Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The value `null` is a reserved word/value in JSON, so it should not be wrapped in quotes or double-quotes. When it is wrapped, it is actually considered to be a string value containing the characters `n`,`u`, `l`, and `l`.

So, try replacing this line:

```
"nextrecurringchargedate": "null"
```

with this line:

```
"nextrecurringchargedate": null
```

Comment: that's the problem, that the data is converted and replaced null to "null". Since it was implemented in the code before me, and I do not understand why it is written